# git revert unchanged files

Tags: git, git-revert

Может ли Git сделать `revert` файла, если у него изменились лишь окончания строк и пробелы?
Аналог команды `git diff -w`

Answer (score 1):

если изменения файлов (не важно, какие) «зафиксированы» коммитом, то, да, к этому коммиту можно применить команду `revert`. именно к коммиту. ко **всему** коммиту, а не к отдельным изменениям.

в результате действия команды `revert` будет добавлен новый коммит, в котором будут «зафиксированы» изменения в тех же самых файлах, противоположные тем изменениям, что были «зафиксированы» первоначальным коммитом.

---

если же под термином «revert» подразумевалась не команда `revert`, а откат ещё не «зафиксированных» изменений в файлах/каталогах, то сделать это можно, например, так:

```
$ git checkout -- путь/к/файлу/или/каталогу ...
```